# Reduce the number of kernels with _GRUB2_/Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: grub2

Dear Community!
I need it to do it automagically:
In the "old days" I just installed the startupmanager and set that that it automaticly only leaved the last 2 fresh kernels, so even if a kernel update came, it did it by itself and I don't had to care about it!
How could I set this on Ubuntu 10.04 *WITH GRUB2*?
CLI or GUI solution - it doesn't matter
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, what I found was "grub-customizer" which helps in a different way than startupmanager, but it also configures what you want if you decide to use BURG instead of GRUB.

Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

[image]

The you can find the launcher  Applications >System Tools >Grub Customizer

Comment: What is the package name of the Grub customizer?

Comment: Hello @LanceBaynes, the "grub-customizer" require you to add it's repository. 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image | grep install | grep -v deinstall | sort | head -n-3 > installedkernels`

Should get you a list of kernels not including the last 2 and the pseudo-package for current.  You could then `cut` the first field and feed it to `sudo apt-get -y remove`

Disclaimer: I am not a fan of automagically doing anything with kernels, so I won't provide the full cut and paste code.  A bit of `man cut` and `man cron`should get you the rest of the way there.